# DB browser lite Querying data

Tags: python, sqlite

```
 column_2 = 'Equipment_Taken'
 table_name = 'Personal_Information'
 column_3 = 'Client_Name'

 dbCursor.execute('SELECT ({coi}) FROM {tn} WHERE {cn1}= "Bob"'.\
            format(coi=column_2, tn=table_name, cn1=column_3))
        all_rows = dbCursor.fetchall()
        print('2):', all_rows)
```

I was wondering how I could switch out the "Bob" string with a userinput, at the moment when I subsitute a userinput such as userinput[2] instead of Bob it gives me a syntax error.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
column_2 = 'Equipment_Taken'
table_name = 'Personal_Information'
column_3 = 'Client_Name'

userinput = input('Enter user name:')

dbCursor.execute('SELECT ({coi}) FROM {tn} WHERE {cn1}= "{input}"'.\
            format(coi=column_2, tn=table_name, cn1=column_3, input = userinput))
all_rows = dbCursor.fetchall()
print('2):', all_rows)
```